# All ComboBoxItem ValueMembers are last item from DataReader

Tags: c#, combobox, sqldatareader

I'm adding items to a ComboBox at runtime. Everything works fine but the problem is that the ValueMember is displaying only the value of the last record in all the items. And I want the current item in the ValueMember.

```
string qr1 = "select * from categorymaster";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qr1, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
cmbcat.Items.Clear();

while (dr1.Read())
{
    cmbcat.Items.Add(dr1[1].ToString());
    cmbcat.DisplayMember = dr1[1].ToString();
    cmbcat.ValueMember = dr1[0].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use value member while looping

```
string qr1 = "select * from categorymaster";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qr1, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        cmbcat.Items.Clear();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            cmbcat.Items.Add(new Item(dr1[1].ToString(), dr1[0].ToString()));

        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: i didnt get it "add item" line.. bt i get solution.. thank u all for replying... :)

Answer (score 3):

`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` refer to names of properties in an object and not to values like in your code. Since you don't populate items with any object but just with values you don't need to set them at all.

But in general your approach needs work! It is better to create objects where you keep both values from your reader in two properties and define the one as your `ValueMember` and the other one as `DisplayMember`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` in your situation you should fill a `DataTable` and set it as `DataSource` to the `ComboBox`:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("ID");
 dt.Columns.Add("CategoryName");

 cmbcat.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
 cmbcat.ValueMember = "ID";
 cmbcat.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you go through an item from the reader in the while-loop, you add an item to the ComboBox. So far so good, but then you set the Display - and ValueMember of the ComboBox to the last item that is read from the reader. So at the end the ComboBox's Display - and ValueMember are equal to the last item that was read.

**Edit:**

For a right solution look at the answers already being given by @ionden en @PraVn: use of a DataTable/Source or just add the items in the loop.